# How can I bypass security filter in web.xml

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I am working with a home grown security filter, SCMIS Security Filter, in our web app that makes a call to an exception java file when the user is not authenticated to access the web app that is located in a dependency JAR file.  This filter is defined in our web.xml file but I would like to know if there is anyway that I can bypass this security filter when this particular exception is called so that I can redirect the user to a specific JSP page in this same web app?

Here is the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID"  version="2.5">

  <display-name>SCMIS</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Waffle SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <display-name>SCMIS Security Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>SCMISSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.texashealth.scmis.security.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <display-name>Stripes Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.StripesFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ActionResolver.Packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.texashealth.scm.stripes,org.texashealth.scmis.stripes</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>Extension.Packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.texashealth.scmis.stripes.ext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>PopulationStrategy.Class</param-name>
            <param-value>net.sourceforge.stripes.tag.BeanFirstPopulationStrategy</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Waffle SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Waffle SecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SCMISSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SCMISSecurityFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <display-name>Stripes Dispatcher</display-name>
        <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The exception method called in the JAR from the filter is:

```
public UnauthorizedException(final HttpServletResponse response, final String userName) throws IOException {
    //response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "User: " + userName.toUpperCase() + " is not authorized to access this resource");
    response.sendRedirect("/nau/unAuthorizedUser.jsp");
}
```

Right now I am getting stuck in a loop when bringing up my local tomcat server because I am in the security filter that keeps trying to authenticate the user for access to web app and I cannot get the user to the unAuthorizedUser.jsp page.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you've mapped the security filter on `*.jsp` which will obviously intercept on all `*.jsp` requests, including the `unAuthorizedUser.jsp` page. There are basically two ways to solve this:

1. You need to change your filter mapping as such it doesn't match the `unAuthorizedUser.jsp` request. For example, change it to `/app/*` and put all restricted pages in `/app` folder.
2. You need to add an extra `if` check on `request.getRequestURI()` to see if `unAuthorizedUser.jsp` is been requested and if so, then skip the authorization check and continue with filter chain.